# How does data.table get the column name from j?

Tags: r, data.table

For example:

```
dt <- data.table()
x=1:5
> dt[,list(2,3,x)]
   V1 V2 x
1:  2  3 1
2:  2  3 2
3:  2  3 3
4:  2  3 4
5:  2  3 5
```

The resulting data.table has column `x`

For some reason, I would like to create a function to simplify data.table construction.

```
tt <- function(a, b, ...){
    list(a=sum(a), b=sum(b), ...)
}

> dt[,tt(1:2,1:3,x)]
   a b V3
1: 3 6  1
2: 3 6  2
3: 3 6  3
4: 3 6  4
5: 3 6  5
```

So whenever I call `list`, I use `tt` instead, so it auto inserts predefined columns for me.
However, now it doesn't recognize the shortcut naming for `x`.

How to improve `tt` to auto name column like `list` in data.table if it is not too hard?

#### Aim

```
dt[,tt(1:2,1:3,x)]
```

Returns

```
   a b  x
1: 3 6  1
2: 3 6  2
3: 3 6  3
4: 3 6  4
5: 3 6  5
```

#### Solution

```
tt <- function(a, b, ...){
    dots <- list(...)
    inferred <- sapply(substitute(list(...)), function(x) deparse(x)[1])[-1]
    if(is.null(names(inferred))){
        names(dots) <- inferred
    } else {
        names(dots)[names(inferred) == ""] <- inferred[names(inferred) == ""]
    }
    c(a=sum(a), b=sum(b), dots)
}

dt <- data.table(c=1:5)
x=1:5

> dt[,tt(1:2,1:3,x,c+1)]
   a b x c + 1
1: 3 6 1     2
2: 3 6 2     3
3: 3 6 3     4
4: 3 6 4     5
5: 3 6 5     6
> dt[,tt(1:2,1:3,x, z=c+1)]
   a b x z
1: 3 6 1 2
2: 3 6 2 3
3: 3 6 3 4
4: 3 6 4 5
5: 3 6 5 6
```

#### Update

Recently I found that there was some bug in page 46 of S Programming from Venables & Ripley. I made some modifications and put it here. Hopefully it would be useful to some people.

```
# Get the best names vector for arguments like what data.frame does.
# Modified from page 46 of S Programming from Venables & Ripley.
# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20545476/how-does-data-table-get-the-column-name-from-j
name.args <- function(...){
    # Get a list of arguments.
    dots <- as.list(substitute(list(...)))[-1]
    # Get names of the members if they have, otherwise "".
    # If a list have no named members, it returns NULL.
    nm <- names(dots)
    # If all arguments are named, return the names directly.
    # Otherwise it would cause a problem when do nm[logic(0)] <- list().
    if (!is.null(nm) && all(nm != ""))
        return(nm)
    # Handle empty argument list case.
    if (length(dots) == 0)
        return(character(0))
    # Get positions of arguments without names.
    fixup <- 
        if (is.null(nm))
            seq(along=dots)
        else
            nm == ""
    dep <- sapply(dots[fixup], function(x) deparse(x)[1])
    if (is.null(nm))
        dep
    else {
        nm[fixup] <- dep
        nm
    }
}

# Example
# x <- 1:2
# name.args(x, y=3, 5:6)
# name.args(x=x, y=3)
# name.args()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A simple solution would be to pass in additional arguments as *named* rather than *unnamed* arguments:

```
dt[,tt(1:2,1:3,x=x)]   ## Note that this uses `x=x` rather than just `x`
#    a b x
# 1: 3 6 1
# 2: 3 6 2
# 3: 3 6 3
# 4: 3 6 4
# 5: 3 6 5
```

Or for the truly lazy, something like this ;)

```
tt <- function(a, b, ...){
    dots <- list(...)
    names(dots) <- as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1])
    c(a=sum(a), b=sum(b), dots)
}
dt[,tt(1:2,1:3,x)]
#    a b x
# 1: 3 6 1
# 2: 3 6 2
# 3: 3 6 3
# 4: 3 6 4
# 5: 3 6 5
```

Comment: of course I know I can always make it explicit... I am looking for a lazy solution.

Comment: OK -- that wasn't as clear from your pre-edit question. Added a solution that will work for unnamed arguments. (If you want to use a combination of named and unnamed additional arguments, you'll likely want to do a bit of additional processing to merge the supplied and implied names.)

Comment: I prefer doing `as.character(substitute(list(...))[-1])` (note that the "list" part is irrelevant, anything will do there as long as it looks like a function) instead of that `sapply(match.call(...` since I've had some issues with the latter

Comment: @eddi -- Yes, thanks. Since your suggestion is cleaner, I'll incorporate it with an edit.

Comment: @eddi -- I see that on page 46 of their MASS book (where they present a souped up version of the above, which handles named and unnamed arguments) Venables & Ripley use `sapply(dots, function(x) deparse(x)[1])`. I bet that `[1]` would avoid the problems that can otherwise arise from using `sapply()`...

Comment: great. Any chance it can still support the named arguments?

Comment: @colinfang -- Glad to hear. For the record, the solution I was thinking of was on page 46 of S Programming (not Modern Applied Statistics with S), also by Venables & Ripley.  Not sure whether it's OK to post that, though, so I won't ;)

Comment: have no access to the book, and google book preview is unavailable for page 46...(page 45,48 are both available). BUT, I managed to find this: http://www.codecollector.net/view/96FEA01C-0295-4147-B458-E499A8F86795-95744-00003EE46A956454#.Uqr4DfRdXqQ

Comment: @colinfang -- That's the one. Google really is amazing.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution relies on [`tibble::lst`](https://tibble.tidyverse.org/reference/lst.html):

```r
library(data.table)

tt <- function(a, b, ...){
  tibble::lst(a=sum(a), b=sum(b), ...)
}

dt <- data.table(c=1:5)
x=1:5

dt[, tt(1:2, 1:3, x, c+1)]
#>    a b x c + 1
#> 1: 3 6 1     2
#> 2: 3 6 2     3
#> 3: 3 6 3     4
#> 4: 3 6 4     5
#> 5: 3 6 5     6
dt[, tt(1:2, 1:3, x, z=c+1)]
#>    a b x z
#> 1: 3 6 1 2
#> 2: 3 6 2 3
#> 3: 3 6 3 4
#> 4: 3 6 4 5
#> 5: 3 6 5 6
```